# can I use IF statement with more than one value?

Tags: oracle

I have a data base with daily tables. I want to write a procedure that will create a view to union all the tables for the days of the month.  I want to catch months with 31 days or 30, and FEB with 29 days.  Is it efficient to use if statement ?

Can I use if statement with more than one value as below?

```
 if(upper(MON)) in ('JAN','MAR','MAY','JUL','AUG','OCT','DEC') THEN {DO SOMETHING}
```

Comment: Why would anyone design tables like that? No offense, but this is a *horrible* data model.

Comment: i need to craete this full montly table please advise me

Comment: When do these tables get created?  When will this view be created?

Answer (score 3):

Given how convoluted your code is, the efficiency of the IF is probably the least of your problems.  I guess your company won't spring for the Partitioning licence. *(Author's note: this sentence refers to the code posted in the original version of the query which the OP has since redacted.)*

However, your approach won't work.  You can't use an IF in DDL like that. You need to do something else.

Your view won't compile unless all the tables already exist.  So I'm going to assume you have some form of scheduled job which creates those tables and then creates the view.  In which case, you can drive the procedure off the data dictionary (Caution: untested code, you may need to fix typos).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE monthly_view (
   MON_P      VARCHAR2,
   YEAR_P    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YY'))
IS
    l_stmt varchar2(32767);
BEGIN

    l_stmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW monthly_view_'|| UPPER (MON_P)|| '_'|| YEAR_P||' as ';
    for r in ( select table_name from user_tables
               where table_name like 'LT_'|| UPPER (MON)||'____'|| YEAR_P||'_BCH'
                  )
     loop
         if r.table_name != 'LT_'|| UPPER (MON)||'_01_'|| YEAR_P||'_BCH'
         then
             l_stmt := l_stmt ||' UNION ALL ';
          end if;
          l_stmt := l_stmt ||' SELECT * FROM '||r.table_name;
      end loop;
      execute immediate l_stmt;
END;
/
```

This approach means only the routine which creates the tables needs to worry about the days of the month and whether it's a leap year.

Even better would be to not have separate tables for each month of each year.

Comment: i need full table for each month of year and please advise me with more efficient  way to do it